# Backbonejs how to set property of all other models in a collection when one model is changed

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a model that represents products (which are shown as LI items in an UL) and a collection that holds these products.

When I click on one LI, I want the underlying model to have a property that is set to true, and for all other models in the collection to have their properties set to false.

```
//Model for product
        var cs_product = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: function(){

                return {
                    name: '',
                    active: false
                };

            },
            initialize: function(){

                if(!this.get('name'))
                    this.set({'name': this.defaults.name});

            },
            toggle: function(){


                this.set({
                    active: !this.get('active')
                });

            }
        });





        //Collection of all products this user has access to
        var cs_products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            _products: [],
            initialize: function(cs_products){
                this._products = cs_products
            },          
            model: cs_product //<-- creates an instance of the cs_product model for each of our products
        });     
        var user_client_products = new cs_products(globals.cs_user.cs_suite_products);
        user_client_products.on('change:active', function(el, i, list){

            console.log('collection change event');
            console.log(arguments);
            console.log(el.toJSON());

            //loop over all models in collection and set active to false except for this?
            this.each(function(el2){

                if(el === el2)
                    return;

                console.log(el2);

                el.set({active: false});


            });


        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Events on models within a collection are also [triggered on the collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection):

> **Backbone.Collection**
>   [...]
>   Any event that is triggered on a model in a collection will also be triggered on the collection directly, for convenience. This allows you to listen for changes to specific attributes in any model in a collection, for example: `Documents.on("change:selected", ...)`

So your collection could listen for `"change:active"` events from its models simply by binding to the `"change:active"` event on itself. Then it could set the rest of the models in itself to not-active:

```
var cs_products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: cs_product,
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'propagate_active');
        this.on('change:active', this.propagate_active);
    },
    propagate_active: function(p) {
        if(!p.get('active'))
            return;
        this.each(function(m) {
            if(p.id != m.id)
                m.set({ active: false }, { silent: true });
        });
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WEkmy/

---

As an aside, there's no reason to track the models in a collection yourself:

```
var cs_products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    _products: [],
    initialize: function(cs_products) {
        this._products = cs_products; // <------------- ????
    },
    //...
});
```

A collection is a list of models with some decorations so all that is baked in. You can access the array of models through [`this.models`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models) inside the collection or you can use the [baked-in Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) to iterate over the collection's models.